# Python Is there any way to make my program keep running even if i close the prompt window and be able to restore it again?

Tags: python, windows, system-tray

Begginer question.

suppose i have this code:

```
x = input(f" give a number ")

while True:
    print(x)
```

when i generate this code in an .exe and open it a terminal opens that asks me for the input and print infinitly in the terminal window the number. I want to be able to close the terminal from the taskbar and the program still is running in the background and if i want to i could like to restore the terminal window to see the program running. maybe create a system tray icon that runs the program?

i tried to create tray icon using pystray and run the above program in threading but didn't manage to make it happen as described.

Comment: `tmux` maybe? Not sure if that runs on Windows, you may have to upgrade to Linux.

Comment: Consider adding a tag for an OS. The question vaguely sounds Windows-centric, in which case that should just explicitly be stated. For Unixes, `screen`.

Comment: Do you want the program to **keep running** in the background, or do you want it to **resume running** with the same value of `x` when you restart it?

Comment: i know you said it is a terminal application, but considering that it clearly isn't the real application above, maybe this will help - I've got an application that using Tkinter, and I used pystray to make the tray icon and then utilized the `withdraw_window()` method in Tkinter to hide/remove the window and remove it from the task menu. The application is available from the tray still and has not closed

Comment: Thanks for the replies.I am sorry i didn't mentioned the os.It's windows.I want the application keep running without a window in taskbar.